# How to change rules in seccomp filter of openssh

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openssh, seccomp

I have done the installation of OpenSSH_6.6p1 with OpenSSL 1.0.1f. It is working fine. There is a `sandbox-seccomp-filter` in OpenSSH_6.6p1. How can I change the rules in the filter and then how to implement the filter again so that OpenSSH can filter the specific system call.

Answer (score 2):

1. Why so old version? Since 6.6 we fixed a lot of issues with seccomp filter. Current version 7.2 works quite fine.
2. [sandbox-seccomp-filter.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sandbox-seccomp-filter.c) contains all you need. Change what you need, recompile and you are done. Reading what is [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) filter and [what does it do](https://outflux.net/teach-seccomp/) and how does it work is also good start.
3. If you will have some specific question, feel free to come with new specific question. Question as it is, is too broad to answer or walk you through all the process.